# C# Download lag

Tags: c#, winforms, download, lag

I have a serious problem. I'm currently doing a patcher program.
There's a "Patch" button in the program, and if the user click it, the download is starting.
There are currently 5 files that the program needs to download. The downloading is correct, this part of the program is working but when I click the Patch button, the program starts lagging, and I can't close, or change the position of it. 
Here's the code:

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.download));
            thread.Start();
        }

```
    public void download()
    {
        int downloaded = 0;
        int all = 5;
        WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();

        if (button1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            MethodInvoker MethodControll = new MethodInvoker(download);
            this.button1.Invoke(MethodControll);
        }
        else
        {

            double state;
            jelenlegidownload.Text = "alut.dll";
            myWebClient.DownloadFile(Files.alutDLL, "alut.dll");
            downloaded++;
            state = downloaded / all * 100;
            progressBar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(state);
            progressBar.Refresh();
            this.Refresh();  

            jelenlegidownload.Text = "BlackBox.dll";
            myWebClient.DownloadFile(Files.BlackBoxDLL, "BlackBox.dll");
            downloaded++;
            state = downloaded / all * 100;
            progressBar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(state);
            progressBar.Refresh();
            this.Refresh();

            jelenlegidownload.Text = "DevIL.dll";
            myWebClient.DownloadFile(Files.DevILDLL, "DevIL.dll");
            downloaded++;
            state = downloaded / all * 100;
            progressBar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(state);
            progressBar.Refresh();
            this.Refresh();

            jelenlegidownload.Text = "fltkdll.dll";
            myWebClient.DownloadFile(Files.fltkdllDLL, "fltkdll.dll");
            downloaded++;
            state = downloaded / all * 100;
            progressBar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(state);
            progressBar.Refresh();
            this.Refresh();

            jelenlegidownload.Text = "glut32.dll";
            myWebClient.DownloadFile(Files.glut32DLL, "glut32.dll");
            downloaded++;
            state = downloaded / all * 100;
            progressBar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(state);
            progressBar.Refresh();
            this.Refresh();
```

The Files.cs:

```
public class Files
{
    public static string alutDLL = "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/62tt9w194xefk7t/alut.dll?token_hash=AAHQmybYdR44TRrS9bWQWV7jlZBzZQ-mmmjNy1Kv_qR4cg&amp;dl=1";
    public static string BlackBoxDLL = "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/vtdrl8qdpky8p08/BlackBox.dll?token_hash=AAHCtQPBJ5s-3aL5B4FqrmOUIGP6BVvW8ZQeWd-xBzysTw&dl=1";
    public static string DevILDLL = "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/spni307vmk4zng9/DevIL.dll?token_hash=AAEmZdQj3dv2NIEh6tcWwkgyJHCytSsX65QXZyNGY2Vl1w&dl=1";
    public static string fltkdllDLL = "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/fsa29pelfwgk5ha/fltkdll.dll?token_hash=AAF55SuU_8bfli5gIiPpA-VLWUmZKLbOK-Ys8iokuJ8_XA&dl=1";
    public static string glut32DLL = "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/cptiwxv17nhtywp/glut32.dll?token_hash=AAGCNXQPpwrByjp-uG_avBbkNyNjTfOJFxbY3ieNAfLzVw&dl=1";
}
```

How can I fix the lagging? (As I said before, if I click the "Patch" button, the files are downloading, but the program "stops")

Answer (score 1):

To stop the download part of your application to block your UI part of the application, why don't you do the download job on a different thread. This way your UI will still be responsive even if the download has not been finished.

Edit: I think this is a great article that applies to your case:

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4134/net-threading-part-i/

Comment: I'm going to try this out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood `InvokeRequired`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx):

> Gets a value indicating whether the caller must call an invoke method
>   when making method calls to the control because the caller is on a
>   different thread than the one the control was created on.

Basically, you start your download on another thread. But since this will cause `InvokeRequired` to be true, you recall the method on the GUI thread, locking the application.

Does it work better if you remove this section?

```
    if (button1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        MethodInvoker MethodControll = new MethodInvoker(download);
        this.button1.Invoke(MethodControll);
    }
```

**Update**
To rule out that your doing something wrong with your progress bar, try simplify your download method to this:

```
public void download()
{
    WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();

    myWebClient.DownloadFile(Files.alutDLL, "alut.dll");
    myWebClient.DownloadFile(Files.BlackBoxDLL, "BlackBox.dll");
    myWebClient.DownloadFile(Files.DevILDLL, "DevIL.dll");
    myWebClient.DownloadFile(Files.fltkdllDLL, "fltkdll.dll");
    myWebClient.DownloadFile(Files.glut32DLL, "glut32.dll");
}
```

This *should* make the files downloaded without lag, but you want see any updates in your progress bar (obviously).

Comment: Still laggy, and in the end, I have an InvalidOperationException.